# KendoUI Resizable widget?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, resize, kendo-window

We are using KendoUI for a project, and we need a 'resizable' widget (or resizable div). Pretty much like a window's resizing functionality, but without the other 'junk' of the window. Is there any way, to extract only the resizing functionality from the kendo window widget?

We really don't want to utilize another UI library, unless it is absolutely necessary.

Since the css3 resizable property is very unsupported, that is not an option.

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: Resize by dragging, to the desired size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert a `div` into a dynamically resizable `div`, you can use Kendo UI window for it and suppress the `title`.

HTML code:

```
<div id="resizable">
    This is a resizable DIV implemented using Kendo UI window.
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#resizable").kendoWindow({
    title: false
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Qer3C/

Comment: Exactly what I need, I have missed that I can turn off the title. Thanks a lot!